# Rotation of 90, 180 and 270 using python and tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to randomly rotate my images in 90, 180, and 270 degrees, that is, by multiples of 90 degrees.

Currently, I am using the `ImageDatagenerator` to augment my data:

```
train_dataGen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=None,horizontal_flip=True,rotation_range=90,
                                   vertical_flip=True)
```

If `rotation_range` variable is equal to 90, like the code above, does it only do rotations of 90 degrees? or does it perform rotations of multiples of 90?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def rotate_image(image):
    return np.rot90(image, np.random.choice([-1, 0, 1]))

train_dataGen = ImageDataGenerator(
    preprocessing_function=rotate_image)
```

This function will rotate by either -90, 0, or 90 degrees.

Comment: OK, thank you! So it does the 90 and 270. Do you have an idea how can I also do the rotation of 180 degrees? Is it equivalent to performing the horizontal flip?

Comment: For 180-degree rotation, you can use `np.rot90(image, 2))`. The second argument specifies the number of 90-degree rotations. This is not the same as the horizontal flip.

Comment: Ah ok so I just have to change the vector `[-1,0,1]` to `[-1,0,1,2]`

Answer (score 0):

To apply these rotations to images, one can use the function `apply_affine_transform()` within keras preprocessing. This function [is used by `ImageDataGenerator`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/6701f27afa62712b34a17d4b0ff879156b0c7937/keras_preprocessing/image/image_data_generator.py#L859-L870) to perform transforms.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x = np.arange(256).reshape(16, 16)
x = np.tile(x[..., np.newaxis], 3)
# x.shape == (16, 16, 3)
plt.imshow(x)
```

[image: theta=0deg]

```py
x_90 = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.apply_affine_transform(x, theta=90)
plt.imshow(x_90)
```

[image: theta=90deg]

```py
x_180 = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.apply_affine_transform(x, theta=180)
plt.imshow(x_180)
```

[image: theta=180deg]

```py
x_270 = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.apply_affine_transform(x, theta=270)
plt.imshow(x_270)
```

[image: theta=270deg]

---

The `rotation_range` parameter of `ImageDataGenerator` specifies a range of possible rotations. A random is taken from the uniform distribution between `-rotation_range` and `rotation_range`. Here is [the source](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/6701f27afa62712b34a17d4b0ff879156b0c7937/keras_preprocessing/image/image_data_generator.py#L759-L764).

```py
if self.rotation_range:
    theta = np.random.uniform(
        -self.rotation_range,
        self.rotation_range)
else:
    theta = 0
```